# Save texts from EditText into spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I'm trying to create a spinner, text field and a button, then when I write something into the text field and click the button, the text will appear in the spinner and won't be disappear even I killed my app or add a new text into the spinner.Any best way to do this?Do I need to store the text into Shared Preferences or I must store them in SQLite Databases?

Answer (score 2):

If your textSpinner will not have much information and you are not planing in using the SQLite database for anything else a Shared Preferences will do just fine. You could convert your list to a HashSet and store it as a Set. More info from the [Official Documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 1):

Store the text into Shared Preferences and load it in OnCreate is a good option.

You can do like this:

Get values from sharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
String str = prefs.getString("KEY", "");
```

Put values on sharedPreferences

```
final EditText editTxt = (EditText) yourView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
String strValue = editTxt .getText().toString();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("KEY", strValue);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Lets say I write "hello" in the text field and it saved in sharedpreferences.If I write "hi" in the same text field and save again, the previous "hello" will still be there or will be deleted?

Comment: Lets say I write "hello" in the text field and saved it in sharedpreferences.After that if I write "hi" in the same text field and save it again, will the previous "hello" still there or it will be removed by "hi".How can I do if I want to save both "hi" and "hello" and some more in sharedpreferences without removing the old data?

Comment: SharedOreferences works like a dictionary with a pair (key,value). If you want you can put a string splitted by ";" and when you return the value make a conversion with split function. then convert to List with list = Arrays.asList(array) and add a value to the list